# Not able to install pypy sandbox

Tags: python, sandbox, pypy

As mentioned in: https://howtoinstall.co/en/python-pypy.sandbox
I tried the following code:

sudo apt-get update and then
sudo apt-get install python-pypy.sandbox

This gives me the following output:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-pypy.sandbox is already the newest version (5.1.2+dfsg-1~16.04).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-pypy.sandbox : Depends: pypy-lib (= 5.1.2+dfsg-1~16.04) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: it is just saying that you already have the package installed

Comment: @Nazkter thanks for the help, but i am still confused about using the sandbox. According to this doc: https://doc.pypy.org/en/release-2.0-beta2/sandbox.html I need to go inside directory pypy/goal, which is nowhere to be found in my system